# Access JSON fields in kebab case (e.g. some-value)

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm having trouble accessing fields in kebab case (e.g. some-value) in React Native when consuming an API.

In other requests the following approach works

Endpoint return:

```
data: {
    attributes: {
        avatar-medium:"/images/medium/work-missing.png",
        company-avatar:"/images/thumb/professional-missing.png",
        company-name:"Company Name"
   }
}
```

Accessing kebab cased fields:

```
const {
    'avatar-medium': avatarMedium,
    'company-avatar': companyAvatar,
    'company-name': companyName
} = this.props.data.attributes;
```

That works, but in this particular JSON as follow returns an error using the same solution:

Endpoint return:

```
data: {
    relationships: professional-company-address {
        data: {…}
    }
}
```

Accessing kebab cased fields (error):

```
const {
    'professional-company-address': companyAddress
} = this.props.data.relationships;
```

**Error:**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'professional-company-address' of undefined

What is difficult to understand because the return of

```
console.log(this.props.data.relationships)
```

Is

```
professional-company-address {
    data: {…}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a synchronicity problem since the fields were empty seconds before completing the request

Solved with:

```
if (this.props.data.length !== 0) {
    console.log(this.props.data.relationships['professional-company-address']);
}
```